# Azure Service Bus message retrieval all have same lock times

Tags: python, azureservicebus, azure-python-sdk

I am having an issue retrieving messages off the Azure Service Bus using the python SDK, in respect to the lock times on the messages, but potentially it may be an issue with my understanding.

```
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name)
receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(
    queue_name,
    sub_queue=ServiceBusSubQueue.DEAD_LETTER,
)

with servicebus_client, receiver, sender:
    while matching_messages < limit:
    
        received_messages = receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=10)
      
        if not received_messages:
            break

        for msg in received_messages:
            print(datetime.now(timezone.utc))
            print(msg.locked_until_utc)
            cprint(f"Processing SequenceNumber: {msg.sequence_number}, MessageId: {msg.message_id}", "light_blue")
```

I am creating a receiver, then using receive messages to retrieve messages in batches. Annoyingly I only ever seem to get 1 message back, even after messing with the max_message_count and prefetch_count, but this is a separate issue.

The issue is that the locked_until_utc time seems to be the same for every message I am retrieving from the service bus, and it seems to be based on the lock timeout + the time of first message

End of script error:

[image: End of Script]

Start of script:

[image: Start of Script]

At the start of the script however, there does seem to be a logical gap between the current time and the locked_until_utc, however this gets smaller and smaller as the lock time essentially gets stuck at a value. I would expect the locked_until_utc to get larger with each batch of messages retrieved, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I am wondering if it is happening because you are receiving the messages from a dead-letter queue. I read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues) but could not find anything concrete. Are you observing the same behavior in primary queue as well? That would indicate a bug in the SDK.

Comment: @GauravMantri just switched over to pointing at the active queue, and still get the same issue. 

I actually have the same script implemented using the .NET SDK so just going to see if I get the same issue there too.

Comment: If it works in .Net, then I would say that it is an issue with the SDK. I would recommend opening up an issue with the SDK team here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues.

Comment: @GauravMantri weirdly enough I seem to get the same issue in .NET, not sure what the best channel for reporting is now.

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub (link in my previous comment). That’s the best way to get the team’s attention.

Comment: @GauravMantri actually that was incorrect, the behavior is as expected in the .NET SDK